# Why fetch adding an "Authorization: Negotiate" header to my request?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

I am sending an HTTP request using `window.fetch`.

I am not setting an authorization header, but the resulting request has one that contains the word "Negotiate" followed by an ID of some kind.

Why might this be?

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Negotiate YH0GBisGAQUFAqBzMHGgMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI9BDtOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBAAEADcAAAAPAA8AKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPSDgyNk43TDJVV1dWRkVNSEJFVQ==
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=dc5hihwn8qk1a4ucnewz1y9x; WT_FPC=id=f6d7b11c-b91a-4ed2-934d-39559d723a1b:lv=1474466610079:ss=1474466610079
Host:localhost:23048
Referer:http://localhost:23900/
system-id:foo
User-Agent:bar
user-id:userId
```

Comment: Looks like Kerberos authentication. Perhaps your machine is bound to a realm, which defines what services you are allowed to access, including HTTP requests. By using your credentials to sign into your computer an encrypted secret key will be created to proof your identity within the realm. This could be it.